# Background transparency for Gnome Terminal

Tags: gnome3, gnome-terminal, nixos

I'm trying to have transparency working for Gnome Terminal.

However this is what I get when I try to edit the profile of gnome-temrinal: there's no background tab where I can set the opacity !?

[image]

I am using NixOs, this is what I have in my pkgs.nix file:

```
environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
    # ...
    gnome3.gnome_terminal
    gnome3.gconf    # I have put it just in case it could help
]
```

Any idea what I should install or configure so as to unlock the background transparency option ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GNOME terminal FAQ states:

> How can I make the terminal transparent?
>
> Since version 3.7 *(NixOS master currently contains version 3.26)* this option has been removed from the Preferences
> dialogue. You can however still get the same effect by setting the
> _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY X property, for example with the [Devil's Pie](https://git.gnome.org/browse/devilspie) or [Devil's Pie II](http://www.gusnan.se/devilspie2/) tools. E.g., set up Devil's Pie to start automatically
> with the session, and create the file ~/.devilspie/gnome-terminal.ds
> with these contents:
>
> (if   (matches (window_name) "gnome-terminal-window-*")   (opacity 90)
> )
>
> You can also use [this](https://gist.github.com/nirbheek/5589105) shell script that however only works for
> existing terminal windows and not automatically for newly created
> ones. - https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Terminal/FAQ#How_can_I_make_the_terminal_transparent.3F

Answer (score 4):

You could change opacity/transparency by changing property `_NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY` via `xprop` command.

Run:

```
xprop -format _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY 32c -set _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY 0x7FFFFFFF
```

and then click on window to set it to 50% opacity.

- `0x7FFFFFFF` - 50% opacity
- `0xFFFFFFFF` - 100% opacity

Set opacity via providing window id (obtained from `xwininfo`):

```
xprop -id 0x3a00006 -format _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY 32c -set _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY 0x7FFFFFFF
```

Comment: Better workaround

Answer (score 4):

Putting this as an answer since I killed quite a bit of time trying to do this in Arch Linux. For Arch Linux, there's a much easier solution. Use the [`gnome-terminal-transparency`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/gnome-terminal-transparency/) package. The `gnome-terminal` which comes with Gnome will be replaced by this one, which supports transparent backgrounds